# HTML Video mute button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have tried to create a function in javascript to mute a html video, and change the icon below to a mute icon that i have downloaded. Need Help. The javascript has to be able to work along side jquery as well

Comment: try to add your sample code and try to explain what you already tried and what problems you came up with. You can use jsfiddle to build an example where people can work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is fairly vague, so I'm guessing that this will answer your question.
If you are using video tags in HTML

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls muted>
  <source src="x" type="video/x">
  <source src="x" type="x">
</video>
```

For Java script

```
<video id="myVideo" width="x" height="x" controls>
....
</video>
<button onclick="enableMute()" type="button">Mute sound</button>
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function enableMute() { 
    vid.muted = true;
}
</script>
```

As for your second questions, I don't quite understand it, please elaborate.

Comment: I have two icons, one that is of a speaker, and one that is a mute icon. i want them to change accordingly

Answer (score 7):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/6cc9mhbb/

on click of the button the icon will change

```
$("video").prop('muted', true);

$(".mute-video").click(function () {
    if ($("video").prop('muted')) {
        $("video").prop('muted', false);
        $(this).addClass('unmute-video'); // changing icon for button

    } else {
        $("video").prop('muted', true);
        $(this).removeClass('unmute-video'); // changing icon for button
    }
    console.log($("video").prop('muted'))
});
```

Comment: That was perfect - I needed to add that the button should look for the nearest video, and not just unmute all muted videoes, but really nice.

Comment: above demo is okay but in the jsfiddle example background images no sowing so i added (mute on/off images) http://jsfiddle.net/faL1vjcn/