# I'm trying to add a mute button to a video that automatically plays. I built the website from an HTML5 template.

Tags: button, video, mute

I'm trying to add a mute button to a video that automatically plays. I built the website from an HTML5 template.

https://cmsonline.com/overview/index.html

```
<div class="swiper-slide overlay overlay-grid-2">
<video src="img/slides/overview.mp4" width="640" height="360" loop></video>
</div>
<div id="thumbnail_a">Mute Video</div>
```

Comment: I tried this solution here, but with no luck.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478062/html-video-mute-button

Comment: 'Muted' didn't work? That's odd. How about you modify custom.js and another line to mute it.

Comment: Add this on line 90 in custom.js, below after the video starts playing. $('#fullscreen-slider .swiper-slide-active video').get(0).muted();

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.

Comment: Did it work? Let me know.

Comment: I'm trying your solution here: https://cmsonline.com/overview/technology.html

I added your code to line 90 {inside the bracket}  
// Has video
if ($('#fullscreen-slider .swiper-slide-active').has('video').length) {
    $('#fullscreen-slider .swiper-slide-active video').get(0).play();
    $('#fullscreen-slider .swiper-slide-active video').get(0).muted();
}

Anything I should do in technology.html  line 73??

Answer (score 0):

You could try grabbing the video element by tag name and then telling it to set muted to true, if muted is set to false and if muted is set to false then set it to true.

```
<div class="swiper-slide overlay overlay-grid-2">
    <video src="https://cmsonline.com/overview/img/slides/overview.mp4" width="640" height="360" autoplay></video>
     <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
 </div>
 <div id="thumbnail_a" onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].muted = (document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].muted == false) ? true:false;">Mute Video
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Comment: This worked great. Is there a way to toggle between on and off?

Comment: Sounds great, one way to do it, is using a ternary operator, so that it toggles based on if muted is true or false, I have updated the answer.