# Video Mute and unmute button

Tags: javascript, video, mute

I'm trying to add a mute/unmute button to a fullscreen background video. I used a piece of javascript which is widely published including on stackoverflow ([HTML Video mute button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478062/html-video-mute-button)). Unfortunately, this defaults to mute. No matter what I try I can't get to default to unmute. Clearly I'm a js newbie.

```
<video class="video" autoplay loop>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<button class="mute-video unmute-video"></button>
```

```
$("video").prop('muted', true);

$(".mute-video").click(function () {
    if ($("video").prop('muted')) {
        $("video").prop('muted', false);
        $(this).addClass('unmute-video'); // changing icon for button

    } else {
        $("video").prop('muted', true);
        $(this).removeClass('unmute-video'); // changing icon for button
    }
    console.log($("video").prop('muted'))
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to wait for the video to be ready in order to access its properties. Try using oncanplay event:

```
$("video").oncanplay = function() {
    $("video").prop('muted', true);
};

$(".mute-video").click(function () {
    if ($("video").prop('muted')) {
        $("video").prop('muted', false);
        $(this).addClass('unmute-video'); // changing icon for button

    } else {
        $("video").prop('muted', true);
        $(this).removeClass('unmute-video'); // changing icon for button
    }
    console.log($("video").prop('muted'))
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Just what I needed. You're a star.